# Linux TCP connection refused

Tags: c, linux, tcp

I am doing a TCP connection program and I want to set the address and connection step as a function. The program can be compiled but when I running it the screen displays: ERROR CONNECTION: Connection refused. Could you please help me? Here is the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit (1);
}
struct sockaddr_in createSockAddr(int portnum)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(portnum);
    return addr;
}

int createServerSocket(struct sockaddr_in serv_addr)
{   
    int newsockfd;
    int sockfd;
    int clilen;
    sockfd =  socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//create socket

    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");


    //bind socket
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR on binding");  
    listen(sockfd,5);//listen
    clilen = sizeof(serv_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, &clilen);//accept
    if (newsockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR on accept");

    return newsockfd;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portnum, clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
    exit (2);
    }
    portnum = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr = createSockAddr(portnum);
    newsockfd = createServerSocket(serv_addr);

    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    return 0; 
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 


void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}
struct sockaddr_in createSockAddr(int portnum)
{

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(portnum);
    return addr;
}

int createClientSocket(struct sockaddr_in sockAddr)
{

    int sockfd;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");//create socket

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&sockAddr,sizeof(sockAddr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    return sockfd;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portnum, n;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(2);
    }
    portnum = atoi(argv[2]);
    serv_addr = createSockAddr(portnum);
    sockfd = createClientSocket(serv_addr);
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);

    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in that code where that eror message could be assembled.  Connect fail at client issues 'ERROR connecting', not 'ERROR CONNECTION:' and errno is not checked upon failure.

Comment: do you have `iptables` running locally configured to drop any inbound connections on unspecified ports?

Comment: No~ Let me see what the iptables is. I am not know about it.

Answer (score 1):

The only questionable thing I see is that you aren't zeroing the `sockaddr_in` structs before you assign the fields. Otherwise, it looks fine. It's a little atypical to pass structures around (as opposed to pointers to those structures) in C but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work. (By "zeroing", I mean `memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr)))`.)

Comment: I have tried but it does not work. Anyway, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

The code compiles (with some minor warnings), but works for me (client ignores the first parameter and expects port at the second).

Please, try again, and you can also run the server and client under the supervision of `strace` which is a great tool to see kernel syscalls that an application performs.

Comment: OK I will try. Thank you~